# xslt: only first node is selected

Tags: html, xslt

I want to write text in a certain order from a HTML file so I use templates which should output their node contents in a certain order. 
This is the XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="div[@class='this']">
        <xsl:text>B=</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="div[@class='b']" />
        <xsl:text>, A=</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="div[@class='a']" />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
      <div class="this">
<div>
  <div> <!-- This div make the xsl fail -->
        <div class="a">Second Class A</div>
        <div class="b">Second Class B</div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="this">
        <div class="b">First Class B</div>
        <div class="a">First Class A</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It fails to select the first node because of the extra div:

```
B=, A=
B=First Class B, A=First Class A
```

Any suggestions?

Regards, Peter

Comment: .//select="div[@class='b']" made it working for any number of tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. Using `//` starts from the root of the document. The solution is to simply remove this, and the expression is the relative to your current node

```
    <xsl:template match="div[@class='this']">
        <xsl:text>B=</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="div[@class='b']" />
        <xsl:text>, A=</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="div[@class='a']" />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
```

Note that you can lead it with a dot. In that case, it would look like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="./div[@class='b']" />
```